# Getting `No implementation found for method Task#startPutData` only for iOS with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I fire up a video uploading task towards `Firestore` with the code as follows:

```dart
   final uploadTask = videoFileRef.putData(
        finalVideoData,
        SettableMetadata(contentType: "video/mp4"),
      );
```

This works with no issue on Android.

But on iOS, I get the following error:

> MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Task#startPutData on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_storage))

What should I do to fix this?

I use cloud_firestore: ^4.13.2

[UPDATE] The whole code runs from within an isolate. And I user `flutter_isolate`.